# How to run the Laravel application using different host with ports?

Tags: ubuntu, laravel-5

I want to run the Laravel application with user given IP address and ports in smart FTP terminal php command. But it throws an error message. Error screen images are attached in below links.

[image: Error image for using different Host with ports]

[image: Running in localhost without assign the host and port]

If any one know the solution for above problem please share the feedback.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please never ever ever post screen shots of text. Instead enter them as code formatted text in your question/answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to serve laravel app outside of your machine!

You need to use the localhost or your machines IP address

and then you can set some port and in that way multiple Laravel apps can be served from your machine